# jQuery how to get input from a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var first_name = $('#content').find('input[name="first_name"]').val();
    console.log(first_name);
  })
</script>

<div id="content">
    <form name="info">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"><input type="submit" id="button">
    </form>
</div>
```

Does not print name in console, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there is anything in the input you are searching for, according to your code you are calling a function on load but the input has no specified value.

Comment: Make sure you have included jQuery successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem right now is that the code you've written is executed immediately when the page loads.

From the way your code looks, it looks like you actually want the form's button to do the console log.

I've altered your code a bit, but here's how you'd:

- Select the Form and the Input
- Declare the variable out of the scope
- Bind onto the form's submit event
- Prevent it from actually submitting
- And logging to console per your example

Altered code below:

```
<script>
$(function() {
            // Save a reference to the input
    var input = $("input[name=first_name]"),
            // Get the form itself
            form = $("form[name=info]"),
            // Storage for your first_name outside of the scope
            first_name = false;
    // Bind to the submit event on the form
    form.bind('submit', function() {
        // Set the first_name to the input's value
        first_name = input.val();
        // Log it out (per your example)
        console.log(first_name);
        // Return false to prevent the form from posting
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div id="content">
    <form name="info">
        First Name: 
        <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
        <input type="submit" id="button">
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm not saying this is the best way to handle whatever you're attempting to do with the form, realistically you shouldn't need an ID on the button, and probably would want to replace the NAME on the form with an ID for the selector. Also using an ID selector to get the input would be recommended as well, as ID selectors are faster than `[name=something]` selectors. (Thanks [gnarf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91914/gnarf) for the comment!)

The variable scoping is also probably somewhat strange in your example, but the above code should be good for learning :)

Answer (score 1):

The method as you've written it only runs once, after the page loads.  At that point the input element doesn't contain a value (i.e. $("#first_name").text() == '').  You can bind the logging statement to the keyup event of the element, to see the text that's being entered into it.

```
$(function() {
    // this code only runs once
    var first_name = $('#content').find('input[name="first_name"]').val();
    console.log(first_name);

    $('#first_name').keyup(function() {
       // this code fires everytime a key is released on the element
       console.log($(this).val());
     });
  })
```

[Demo on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iohV3VND3BjByKWlCMm0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/395qZ/1/) for your code.

```
<div id="content">
    <form name="info">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="something">
        <input type="submit" id="button">
    </form>
</div>


$('#content form').on('submit', function () {
    console.log($('#content').find('input[name="first_name"]').val());
});
```

'Something' is the default value.' Try other words in the text box and you will see the new value in console.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you are getting correct results.

Your defined function is never called because you have not attached any events to it.

I have modified your code and you can check it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdQqC/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first_name").focusout(function(){
    var first_name = $(this).val();
     alert(first_name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content form').on('submit', function () {
     console.log(
       $(this).find('input[name="first_name"]').val()
      );
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

edit: you must run your jQuery selection after you have inputted something into the input field. Right now when you run it, it is empty

edit: try using this 'on' from the jQuery docs
http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('#content form').on('submit', function () {
    console.log($('#content').find('input[name="first_name"]').val(););
}
```

Comment: This is in no way true `$(function(){` notation is a short hand for `$(document).ready(function(){`. The only thing required is to have the jquery library loaded before any jquery calls are made.